# Label for Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor, radio-button

I have a radio button in the razor view page, for which im struggling to get the label value using jQuery,

```
<div class="row col-lg-offset-2 ">
            <h4><strong><span>Is Account Modified??:</span></strong></h4>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsModified, true) @Html.Label("Yes")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsModified, false) @Html.Label("No")
            <br>
        </div>
```

I tried to wrap the radio button under `<label>` tag, but that doesn't work. to get the label value. Im trying the following

```
$("input[name='IsModified']:checked").html()
```

Edit 1: It's rendered in the web page as follows

```
<div class="row col-lg-offset-2 ">
            <h4><strong><span>Is Account Modified?:</span></strong></h4>
            <input checked="checked" data-val="true" id="IsModified" name="IsModified" type="radio" value="True" /> <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
            <input id="IsModified" name="IsModified" type="radio" value="False" /> <label for="No">No</label>
            <br>
        </div>
```

Any suggestions would help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `label` will be a sibling of the radio `input`, so you can use `next()`:

```js
var labelText = $("input[name='IsModified']:checked").next('label').text();

console.log(labelText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-lg-offset-2 ">
  <h4><strong><span>Is Account Modified?:</span></strong></h4>
  <input checked="checked" data-val="true" id="IsModified" name="IsModified" type="radio" value="True" /> <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
  <input id="IsModified" name="IsModified" type="radio" value="False" /> <label for="No">No</label>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: It's giving the empty string, doesn't work. Can u think of any other way please?

Comment: In which case can you provide a more complete code sample, showing the output HTML (not the Razor code) and the JS context you're running this code in.

Comment: Given that HTML the code works fine. I edited my answer to show a runnable snippet showing the output. If it doesn't work for you, check the console for errors elsewhere in your code

Comment: Thank u, it works. One more thing im trying here thats not working, im trying to make "Yes" to be selected as default, im using the following,           
    (model => model.IsMetered, true, new {checked = "checked"})                      but its not working. Where am i doing wrong?